# Complimentary DNA strand in c

Tags: c

I am trying to have the user input a strand of DNA, then 
1.) have the string reversed, 
and 2.) replace every character with its complement,  i.e. reverse the string, then replace 'A' with 'T', 'T' with 'A', 'G' with 'C' and 'C' with 'G'. What I have so far:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>


int main()
{
    int reverse(char[]);
    int replace(char[]);
    char s[1000];
    int c;
    int i;
    printf("Enter the String\n");
    scanf("%s",&s);
    reverse(s);
    replace(s);
}


int reverse(char s1[])
        {
int c,i,j;
    for(i=0,j=strlen(s1)-1;i<j;i++,j--) {
        c=s1[i],s1[i]=s1[j],s1[j]=c;
    }

    printf("The complementary string is:%s\n",s1);

    return 0;
}

int replace(char s[])
{

    int j = 0;

    while (s[j] != '\0')
    {
        if (s[j] == 'A')
        putchar('T');
    } 
    if (s[j] == 'T')
    {
        putchar('A');
    } 
    if (s[j] == 'G') 
    {
        putchar('C');
    } 
    if (s[j] == 'C')
    {
        putchar('G');

        } 
    else 
    {
            putchar('*');
        }
        j++;

    return 0;
}
```

As this is my first question I was afraid it might be hard to articulate. I'm also embarrassed I used "complimentary" instead of complementary. Hopefully this explanation is more clear.

EDIT: The post was edited to be more clear (hopefully).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several things going on in your code:

When you read a string with the `%s` format in `scanf`, you should pass a `char` array. Because such arrays "decay" into pointers in function calls, you should not take its address with `&`:

```
scanf("%s\n", s);
```

(The `%s` format is different from the scalar (non-array) formats where you have to pass the address of an integer or floating-point number.)

Your `replace` function has an infinite loop, because the closing brace of the `while` come way before you increment your control variable `j`. This would have been easy to spot if you has formatted your code properly.

It looks as if you opted for printing the string (as opposed to replacing the characters in place) because

```
if (s[j] == 'A') s[j] = 'T';
if (s[j] == 'T') s[j] = 'A';
```

would swap an A to T and then back again. There are many possible ways to get around this. A nice solution is to write an extra function that returns the complement for each letter:

```
int complement(int c)
{
    if (c == 'A') return 'T';
    if (c == 'T') return 'A';
    if (c == 'C') return 'G';
    if (c == 'G') return 'C';
    return '*';
}
```

This will make the `replace` function straightforward.

```
void replace(char s[])
{
    int j = 0;

    while (s[j]) {
        s[j] = complement(s[j]);
        j++;
    }
}
```

(I've made that function `void`, because it doesn't return anything meaningful. You could do the same for `reverse`.)

Comment: Thank you sir! I did notice when I executed that the while loop was implemented improperly, I should have corrected before I posted. It is always best to use void when the function returns nothing or is it preference?